# Android Layout: Have two buttons side by side

Tags: android

I have a simple design for my app: (its my first... ;))
[image]

So, as you can see it is just a background and two buttons. (There are 2 more buttons in it, by they are not important at the moment)

So, I have no idea how to put them next to one another, all they do is be on top of one another. I tried weight to, but that didnt work.

This is my axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/startthehatching_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/StartButton" />
    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/stopthehatching_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/StopButton" />
    <CheckBox
        android:text="Pro Mode On"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxProMode" />
    <Button
        android:text="Help!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/HelpButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Could I just get some help? its probably super easy, but I'm new to this :)

THANKS!!

Comment: make the orientation of the linearlayout horizontal, because the buttons are aligned horizontally

Comment: you can try RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.. it's much better

Comment: which is it the one that looks the same on all phones?

Comment: Do you have any image that contains the actual design that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: well yeah its the one u see on top. this is what it looks like right now: http://imgur.com/a/rslCy

so its a mixture of both the round buttons and then the checkbox and the help button below somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Create a `RelativeLayout` as a `root` layout. As your design contains `bottom-center` aligned `Checkbox` and `Button`, so its better to use `RelativeLayout` as a `container/root` layout.

**2.** Add a direct child horizontal `LinearLayout` and this layout contains 2 child `RelativeLayout` and both has equal width.

**3.** Place `START` and `STOP` button to respective `RelativeLayout`.

**3.** Add `attribute android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to button `START` and `STOP` to align `vertically` inside child `RelativeLayout`

**4.** Add `two` different background `color` to `two` child `RelativeLayout` instead of using background `image` to `root` layout.

**FYI**, As I used two `RelativeLayout's` for two parts, so its better to use background `color` instead of using `image`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#16A25B"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/StartButton"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/startthehatching_button" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#16909D"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/StopButton"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/stopthehatching_button" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/HelpButton"
        android:text="Help!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxProMode"
        android:text="Pro Mode On"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/HelpButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

FYI, You should define the `height-weight` of `Button` into different `dimens.xml` for all `resolutions` to show exact same on all different devices.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: thanks again! i have another favor to ask, would you mind writing a little bit about what u did and how this works? i mean very basic, i know most of the things, but for example i dont understand why u set a background color for certain things... would u do that ? that would be awesome!!

Comment: I have given an explanation as per your question. see my updated answer.

Comment: perfect, you are the best! :)

Comment: hey once again. Now, if I wanted to add a button to the upper right corner of this whole thing, without of course changing anything to the already perfect layout. how would i do this? :) just a hint be awesome :)

Comment: just add a button below checkbox and add attribute `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Comment: If you still facing problem then its better to raise a question and give me the link. I will solve it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Change the orientation to horizontal and make the with be 0dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/StartButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/startthehatching_button" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/StopButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:background="@drawable/stopthehatching_button" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hey thanks! i did that and the started being next to one another. but they are not round anymore xD they became oval and way to big -.-

Comment: @user7285912 You can wrap the buttons in frame layout and add margin="parent_center" on the button, and width=0dp on the frame layout

Comment: can you please give the start and stop button image?

Comment: @FerdousAhamed try this

Comment: hi again, the buttons looks exactly like this: http://imgur.com/a/HFZTR / http://imgur.com/a/0ts44

Comment: check my answer. hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

```
 this code help you!!!

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:background="@drawable/background">
        <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/startthehatching_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/StartButton" />
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/stopthehatching_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/StopButton" />
           </LinearLayout>
           <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
             <CheckBox
             android:text="Pro Mode On"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:id="@+id/CheckBoxProMode" />
            <Button
             android:text="Help!"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:id="@+id/HelpButton" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wow thanks for your help. but it didnt work. I think the problem is that there are two more buttons right underneath. Anyway, in this layout somehow both buttons are not different sized...